# Create apex class in production using force.com migration tool

Tags: apex

Is it possible to create an apex class directly in production environment using force.com migration tool ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't create or develop/change classes directly in a production org using any tool unfortunately. Changes must be made by change sets, or the deploy feature of an IDE.

Meaning even if the migration tool allowed you to create a file, you couldn't populate it.

Edit to say: The migration tool of course does provide a Deploy feature itself, which lets you effectively create (locally) and immediately promote a class to an org. This will still invoke run-all-tests every time it is promoted. - just in case I have read too much emphasis on the word "directly" in your question.